# Função do caractere especial: '=' no nome de métodos

Tags: ruby, método

Boa tarde pessoal.

Sei que o Ruby aceita três caracteres especiais no nome de métodos: '!', '?' e '='. Preciso saber o que o "=" indica e o que faz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método que contém o caractere especial "=" indica que aquele método é um setter.

Em Java, definimos um setter desta forma:

```
public class Welcome{
    private int number;

    public void setNumber(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Em Ruby, um setter é definido desta forma:

```
class Welcome
  def hello=(mymessage)
    @message = mymessage
  end
end
```

Caso queira mais informações, segue o link da documentação sobre este assunto: [Ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html#UB)

Link da mesma pergunta no fórum internacional: [What does the equal ('=') symbol do when put after the method name in a method definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398919/what-does-the-equal-symbol-do-when-put-after-the-method-name-in-a-method-d)